# Set distance between chapter and start of text

Tags: spacing, chapters, templates, books

I'm using the Wiley Template, that can be found here (http://www.latextemplates.com/template/wiley-book-style).

I'm trying to change the spacing between the chapter title and the beginning of the text. To be clear, this region shown in the figure below.

[image]

Does anyone know where I can set this parameter?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle This is a personal project for some non-commercial materials.

Comment: The Wiley website actually provides two templates, not just one. Which one do you use?

Comment: @Mico the 7″ by 10″ Template

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's the definition of `\@makechapterhead` - the macro in charge of setting the chapter heading components (I've added indentation):

```
\def\@makechapterhead#1{% 
  \vglue10pt
  \SpaceAboveChapterNumber=36pt
  {\parindent \z@ 
    \interlinepenalty\@M
    \Large
    \hbox to\textwidth{\hbox{\chapternumberfont CHAPTER
      \the\c@chapter}\hfill\vrule depth12pt width0pt}
    \hrule height3pt
    \vtop to22.5pc{\vfill
      \hyphenpenalty10000
      \raggedright
      \parfillskip=0pt
      \LARGE\boldmath\bfseries\chaptertitlefont 
      #1\vskip1pc
      \hrule height 1pt
      \vskip7pc}}
  \dooffprintinfo}
```

After setting the chapter number, the chapter title is set inside a box of height `22.5pc`. The top of this box has a `\vfill` to push everything inside to the bottom. Then, at the bottom, there's the chapter title (set `\raggedright`), a small skip (`\vskip1pc`), a horizontal rule (`\hrule height 1pt`) and then a large skip (`\vskip7pc`). Here's a visual of the last major skips (the [`showframe` package](//ctan.org/pkg/showframe) was added to highlight the text block boundary):

[image]

You can patch `\@makechapterhead` to remove this using [`etoolbox`](//ctan.org/pkg/etoolbox), or edit the template to change the lengths. Below is an `etoolbox` patch, which reduced the large `22.5pc` vertical box to `10pc` and also only leaving a `2pc` gap between the horizontal rule and the start of the chapter text.

```
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
% Reduce chapter title vertical box height
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\vtop to22.5pc}% <search>
  {\vtop to10pc}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
% Reduce space between chapter title and main text
\patchcmd{\@makechapterhead}% <cmd>
  {\vskip7pc}% <search>
  {\vskip2pc}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
```

[image]

Comment: It worked the way I wanted, but unfortunately it is no longer possible use the \chapterauthors command as it overlaps the title, but that's fine.

Comment: @Mrcrg: If you are interested in an alternative, provide a minimal document that replicates your current setup so we have a similar foundation to work from.